# What is the best way to make my wordpress post static?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website providing football tips with odds. The site is fully automated via cron job, so it automatically posts upcoming matches with odds on a daily basis from xml data sources.
I have also created a plugin, and have used shortcodes to display dynamic content based on available odds data on the posts.

For example. team a vs team b, odds are 1.0 for home win, 2.0 for draw, 3.0 for away win. I have shortcodes in my posts that will then display certain content based on available odds.

Every week my database gets quite full with data, so I am having to make it delete old odds data from 1 week..
Once odds data gets removed, the posts loses its content as they are linked to my plugin. Does anyone know the best way to make the content static and remain on the page without being lost once odds data are removed?

I don't want to transfer the plugins to the post page as I have a lot of plugins and worried it will slow the cron job.

I want to know how I can keep the content on the page

Comment: How much data a week are we talking about? MySQL should be able to handle millions or billions of rows.

Comment: well my current web host is cheap so theres a limit of how many data it can store..

Comment: @KepaZouma, if you know about WordPress it is fully dynamic and its data is Database driven. So if anything deleted from the database it cant be shown into your page, unless you are not maintaining the structure of WordPress.

Comment: @KepaZouma Seems like the simpler solution would be getting a better host, then.